# Pandas - How to fill column with range time conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have a dataset with different columns: the activity description and when it's started and ended

```
    Activity    Start       End      In time
    Activity 1  10:44:26    15:02:24    
    Activity 2  15:22:42    13:52:54    
    Activity 3  14:41:57    16:03:48    
    Activity 4  11:16:08    13:37:16    
    Activity 5  15:49:39    08:51:18    
    Activity 6  19:36:37    15:19:26    
    Activity 7  14:47:33    19:39:29    
    Activity 8  15:40:52    19:30:26
```

How can i fill in Pandas the column "In time" with this condition:

- if **Start is > 8AM** and **End is < 5:30PM** is in time else is not in time.

I tried with datetime module, pd.between_time()... I created my own def but it doesn't work.

How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
#if necessary convert to times
#df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start']).dt.time
#df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End']).dt.time

from datetime import time

mask = (df.Start > time(8,0,0) ) & (df.End  < time(17,30,0))

df['In time'] = np.where(mask, 'yes','no')
print (df)
    Activity     Start       End In time
0  Activity 1  10:44:26  15:02:24     yes
1  Activity 2  15:22:42  13:52:54     yes
2  Activity 3  14:41:57  16:03:48     yes
3  Activity 4  11:16:08  13:37:16     yes
4  Activity 5  15:49:39  08:51:18     yes
5  Activity 6  19:36:37  15:19:26     yes
6  Activity 7  14:47:33  19:39:29      no
7  Activity 8  15:40:52  19:30:26      no
```